# equivalent redshift sql from oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, amazon-redshift, oracle-sqldeveloper

what is the equivalent of the Oracle SQL `in out` in redshift sql? I'm trying to translate some Oracle sql to amazon's redshift sql and it seems like `in out` is a custom function only available in Oracle, what is the equivalent of this in redshift, I couldn't find anything in the documentation.

ex:

```
(test in out go.go_report.line, param date, as_of varchar2, company varchar2)
```

returns an error in out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redshift supports `INOUT` parameter and it is clearly mentioned in the documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_PROCEDURE.html) as

> The argument mode can be IN, OUT, or INOUT. The default is IN.

In more description:

> INOUT arguments are input and output arguments at the same time. Input
> arguments include both IN and INOUT arguments, and output arguments
> include both OUT and INOUT arguments.

Comment: ahh I missed that, Thanks!

Comment: If this answer solved your issue then you can accept this answer so thay this question is marked as resolved.